# mongoose: unique field isn't working

Tags: node.js, mongoose, unique

I'm trying to find out how to enforce unique on a field which isn't an index.

I've seen similar question in here, but the answer of using **dropDups: true** is mentioned to be depcrated.

what is the correct way of enforcing unique on a field?

```
const users = new Schema({
email: { type: String, required: true , unique: true},
...});
```

Comment: I think your code is perfect, i will work. are you getting issue when using index ?

Comment: i just found out in mongoose API:
A common gotcha for beginners is that the unique option for schemas is not a validator. It's a convenient helper for building MongoDB unique indexes.
so i guess that for non-index fields that i want to be unique i need to manually write a validation

Comment: @YoniMayer how would you reliably check if a value is unique _without_ using an index?

Answer (score 7):

Use this
 [mongoose-unique-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator)

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
 
// Define your schema as normal.
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, index: true, unique: true, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
});
 
// Apply the uniqueValidator plugin to userSchema.
userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Why on Earth do we need another 3rd party package to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like this, It will not work for unique key validation.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    username : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        index : {
            unique : true,
            dropDups : true
        }
    });
```

**So you doing it in correct and best way right now, just do it like this**

Drop the collection from database using following command

```
> db.<collection name>.drop()
```

Then restart server and check by doing in this way.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    username : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique : true
    });
```

Comment: Thx JosephM,
But what i was aiming for is unique on fields that are not-index.

Comment: here username is not index,  you can check index fields by db.<collection>.getIndexes().